# Kotlin, when to delegate by map?

Tags: delegates, kotlin

I checked the documentation on `delegate`, and I found there was a provided delegate type `map`:

```
class MutableUser(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var name: String by map
    var age: Int     by map
}
```

But I couldn't figure out what's the difference between the version without `delegate`, like this:

```
class MutableUser(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

And what's the common usage for the delegate `by map`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Difference is that in the first example with delegate, all you have to do is to put map to the constructor and done.

```
val user = MutableUser(mutableMapOf(
        "name" to "John Doe",
        "age"  to 25
))

println(user.name) // Prints "John Doe"
println(user.age)  // Prints 25
```

But for this to work the same with your second example, you have to implement initialization of properties from map yourself.

```
class MutableUser(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init {
        name = map["name"].toString()
        age = map["age"].toString().toInt()
    }
}
```

One common use case would be implementing a JSON parser.

- [Storing Properties in a Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map)

Comment: The other way around works too - when you modify `name`, the map is modified accordingly